# Pass S3 details to AWS lambda function invoked by file analysis step in AWS step function

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can see that the lambda function invoked by a file analysis step in an AWS step function
provides the file content in json format. So my requirement was like, i would like to have the s3 file name of the processed file available in the received event in the lambda function invoked by file analysis step. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: I do need the file content also. but as an add on , my requirement would need the s3 key also

Comment: Which file analysis step you are referring here? Do you have any example  or code?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal I hope you are familiar with AWS step function state known as File analysis used to get processed data from a csv or json file from s3 bucket.

Comment: `{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "File Analysis",
  "States": {
    "File Analysis": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "DISTRIBUTED",
          "ExecutionType": "STANDARD"
        },
        "StartAt": "Lambda Invoke",
.................................................................................................